# How add an annotation on all properties of EF generated entities which identifies a database relation with the T4 template?

Tags: entity-framework, virtual, t4, relation, icollection

When I update model from database on entity framework, it creates the entities with its members:

```
public string COLUMN { get; set; }
```

and, if the entities has relations, it adds something like this:

```
public virtual ICollection<ANOTHER_TABLE> ANOTHER_TABLE { get; set; }
```

What I want to know is:

How can I add an annotation (which is [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore]) for all properties which were created because of relation?

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
   var navigationProperties = typeMapper.GetNavigationProperties(entity);
   ....

    foreach (var navigationProperty in navigationProperties)
    {
#>
    <#=codeStringGenerator.NavigationProperty(navigationProperty)#>
<#
    }
}
```

with

```
    foreach (var navigationProperty in navigationProperties)
    {
#>
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore]
    <#=codeStringGenerator.NavigationProperty(navigationProperty)#>
<#
    }
}
```